# Why std::tuple comparison calls operator bool when operator< overload is provided

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

```
#include <tuple>

struct X {
    int i = 0;
    friend constexpr bool operator<(const X &l, const X &r) noexcept {
        return l.i < r.i;
    }
};

struct Y {
    int i = 0;
    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept {
        return i != 0;
    }
    friend constexpr bool operator<(const Y &l, const Y &r) noexcept {
        return l.i < r.i;
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr X a{1}, b{2};
    static_assert(std::tie(a) < std::tie(b));

    constexpr Y c{1}, d{2};
    static_assert(c < d);
    // assert failed
    // static_assert(std::tie(c) < std::tie(d));

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with C++20.

Line `static_assert(std::tie(c) < std::tie(d));` will fail. It turns out that when comparing `c` and `d`, `operator bool` is called instead of `operator<`. Why would `operator bool` get involved in the first place?

I find this quite surprising. Is this intended or a bug?

Comment: Make the `bool` conversion operator `explicit`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! this will solve the issue. I should not have left it non-explicit. But still, why would it prefers `bool` conversion?

Comment: It looks like something about C++20 and the spaceship operator is to blame.  The code [works fine in C++17 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb0a2d4fe9346279) but [fails in C++20](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf9f490e10f4513b).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the code was always questionable: note that `static_assert(c < d)` but also `static_assert(!(d > c))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When comparing two `tuple<T>`s, named `t1` and `t2`, the `operator<=>` overload for `tuple` will use `get<0>(t1) <=> get<0>(t2)` to compare elements when type `T` satisfies `three_­way_­comparable`; otherwise, it will use `operator<`.

Since `Y` is implicitly convertible to `bool`, this makes `y <=> y` a valid expression and satisfies `three_­way_­comparable`, such that `std::tie(c) < std::tie(d)` (unexpectedly) invokes `bool(c) <=> bool(d)` in your example.

Comment: Your answer is great.. But the fact it works like this makes me really sad :(

Comment: Implement `operator <=>` instead of `operator <` for your types.

Comment: @Jarod42: But then you lose compatibility with a whole lot of compilers which implement older (but still recent) standards of C++.